# TypeError when print statement says otherwise?

Tags: python

this is a very weird situation honestly:

```
def next_feed():        
    print('This is the batch:',batch_query,' and this is the type:', type(batch_query)) # This returns "This is the batch: [3, 20, 11]  and this is the type: <class 'list'>"
    print(batch(batch_query)) # This throws the error
```

Now, it could also be an error in `batch()`:

```
def batch(inputs, max_sequence_length=None):
    """
    Args:
        inputs:
            list of sentences (integer lists)
        max_sequence_length:
            integer specifying how large should `max_time` dimension be.
            If None, maximum sequence length would be used

    Outputs:
        inputs_time_major:
            input sentences transformed into time-major matrix
            (shape [max_time, batch_size]) padded with 0s
        sequence_lengths:
            batch-sized list of integers specifying amount of active
            time steps in each input sequence
    """

    sequence_lengths = [len(seq) for seq in inputs]
    batch_size_ = len(inputs)

    if max_sequence_length is None:
        max_sequence_length = max(sequence_lengths)

    inputs_batch_major = np.zeros(shape=[batch_size_, max_sequence_length], dtype=np.int32)  # == PAD

    for i, seq in enumerate(inputs):
        for j, element in enumerate(seq):
            inputs_batch_major[i, j] = element

    # [batch_size, max_time] -> [max_time, batch_size]
    inputs_time_major = inputs_batch_major.swapaxes(0, 1)

    return inputs_time_major, sequence_lengths
```

but, I don't see how that could happen, nor I see it on the error (I mean if the error occured on batch it would have logged it, right?)

> File "xxxxxx.py", line 181, in next_feed 
>       -   print(batch(batch_query)) 
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

For this to happen if I remember correctly `batch_query` must have been assigned an int ( so something like this `batch_query = 1`) although this kind of operation is not present in my code.

Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: It looks like `batch_query = [3, 20, 11]` is a simple list, whereas the `batch()` function expects a list of lists of integers according to its documentation. Are you sure your input is formatted appropriately? I tried with `batch_query = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]` and the function runs without any error.

Comment: You are overwriting `batch` somewhere. Try `print(batch)`

Comment: @MegaIng Yes, that seems to be the case. Weird as the IDE should have told me this.